# How can I create a cover-page style text file via Linux script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd firstly like to point out that I'm a total noob when it comes to Linux scripting, but I'm trying to create a cover page via script and am totally lost when it comes to formatting.

So far, I have

```
#!/bin/bash

studentName = "Jeremy"

studentNum = "0281190"
courseSection = "702"

read -p "Please enter Course Name: " courseName

read -p "Please enter Course Number: " courseNum

read -p "Please enter Instructor Name: " instrutorNam

read -p "Please enter Submission Date: " subDate

read -p "Please enter Submission Title: " subName

read -p "Submission Subject: " subSubject

touch CoverPage.txt

echo $subName $subDate   >> CoverPage.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is have a user enter the main information contained in a cover page, but the best output I've ended up with so far is just cluttered into the top corner.

Apologies in advance for lack of clarity, just not sure where to start.

Comment: could you provide sample `Cover Page`?

Comment: It's just a basic text file, I'm mostly looking to center the elements and add indentation. Edit for clarification: all printed variables go top left by default, but centered text mid page is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Create, as close as you can, the output you want to see in a code block. Also "centered" against what? 80 columns? For printing?

Answer (score 0):

This bash function will center any text on the screen:

```
ctr() { s="$*"; width=$(( ($COLUMNS + ${#value})/2 )); printf "%${width}s\n" "$s"; }
```

If you don't want the text centered on the screen but rather centered according to some specified width, then replace `$COLUMNS` with that width.

Example (which was centered on my terminal not your browser):

```
$ ctr Hello World
                                       Hello World
```